# GWT Deployment Confusion, Please give some guidelines

Tags: gwt

I wanted to know one thing. When deploying a GWT application on
the server, lets say an application in which there are client  files
Greeting.java(entrypoint), service.java,serviceAsync.java and server
file serviceImpl.java(), only the client files will converted to
javascript. After compilation, I take the war file and place it on the
server, but where to place the server file that is serviceImpl.java???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The war file will also contain a `/WEB-INF` folder with the `web.xml` your libs and the other java classes needed for the server side.

So you only need to copy your war file in the proper `webapps` folder from your server.

Comment: I have created a default application with GWT and compile it. Then I place the file on the tomcat/webapps. Tomcat is running without any problem but it saying that it cannot contact the server

Comment: Which file are you copying? You need a war file. In other words, you need everything from the war folder packet in a zip file (with .war extension)

Comment: Yes, this is what I am using, If u want, i can send u the file through your mail if u me give me it and check it, u know, i'm in a great mess, i need to know this by today, thus if u can help, it would be great!!

Comment: If you check my profile you'll find blog. My email is the same <blogname>@gmail.com ;)
Sorry, just trying to avoid spam. I'll take a look later.